# How to add MouseListener to item on Java Swing Canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas, position

I'd like to make a Java panel that creates objects where the user clicks. Since my actual application uses a MVC approach I'd like also for these objects to be able to repaint themselves when a model is changed, and provide menus to change their properties.

I think that the best way to control their x and y locations would be to take a canvas based approach whereby the `JPanel` calls a draw method on these objects from the `paintComponent` method. This however will only draw the shape on the canvas and does not add the object itself loosing all abilities to control object properties. I'd be very grateful if someone could tell me the best approach for what I want to do.

I've created some sample code which can be seen below. When clicked I'd like the circle to change colour, which is implemented using a MouseListener (it basically represents changing the models properties in this small example). Also I'd just like to make sure that zooming in/out still works with any sample code/advice can provide so I've added buttons to zoom the objects in and out as a quick test.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

public class Main  {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                ExamplePanel panel = new ExamplePanel();

                frame.add(panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    //I could not get this to with when it extended JLayeredPane
    private static class ExamplePanel extends JPanel {
        private static final int maxX = 500;
        private static final int maxY = 500;
        private static double zoom = 1;
        private static final Circle circle = new Circle(100, 100);

        public ExamplePanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(maxX, maxY));
            this.setFocusable(true);

            Button zoomIn = new Button("Zoom In");
            zoomIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    zoom += 0.1;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            add(zoomIn);

            Button zoomOut = new Button("Zoom Out");
            zoomOut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    zoom -= 0.1;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            add(zoomOut);


            // add(circle); // Comment back in if using JLayeredPane
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.scale(zoom, zoom);
            super.paintComponent(g);

            circle.paint(g); // Comment out if using JLayeredPane
        }

    }

    static class Circle extends JPanel {
        private Color color = Color.RED;
        private final int x;
        private final int y;
        private static final int DIMENSION = 100;

        public Circle(int x, int y) {
            // setBounds(x, y, DIMENSION, DIMENSION);
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    color = Color.BLUE;
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                }
            });
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setPaint(color);
            g2.fillOval(x, y, DIMENSION, DIMENSION); 
        }

        // I had some trouble getting this to work with JLayeredPane even when setting the bounds
        // In the constructor
        // @Override
        // public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        //     g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        //     g2.setPaint(color);
        //     g2.fillOval(x, y, DIMENSION, DIMENSION); 
        // }

        @Override
        public  Dimension getPreferredSize(){
            return new Dimension(DIMENSION, DIMENSION);
        }
    }
}
```

As an aside I did try using a `JLayeredPane`(useful because I'd also like to layer my objects) but could not get my objects to even render. I know it has no default layout manager so tried calling `setBounds` in the circle in the constructor, but sadly it did not work. I know it's better to use a layout manager but can't seem to find one suitable for my needs!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't override `paint` components, use `paintComponent` and don't forget to call `super.paintComponent`

A component already has a concept of "location", so when painting, the top left position of your component is actually `0x0`

What you are doing is actually painting beyond the boundaries of you component

For example, if you place your `Circle` at `100x100` and then did...

```
g2.fillOval(x, y, DIMENSION, DIMENSION);
```

You would actually start painting at `200x200` (100 for the actual location of the component and 100 for you additional positioning).

Instead use

```
g2.fillOval(x, y, DIMENSION, DIMENSION);
```

And go back and try using `JLayeredPane`.

You could actually write your own layout manager that takes the location of the component and it's preferred size and updates the components bounds and then apply this to a `JLayeredPane`.  This gives you the "benefits" of an absolute layout, but keeps you within how Swing works to update its components when things change.

You should also be careful with doing anything like...

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

The `Graphics` context is a shared resource.  That means, anything you apply to, will still be in effect when the next component is painted.  This may produce some strange results.

Instead try using...

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
//...
g2.dispose();
```

**Updated**

For zooming I would take a closer look at JXLayer (or JLayer in Java 7)

The JXLayer (and excellent PBar extensions) have gone quite on the net, so you can grab a copy from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/re1hmvypp19oqy1/JXLayer-PBJar-Demo.zip)

(I tried finding a better example, but this is the best I could do with the limited time I have available)

[image]

**Updated with working zooming example**

[image: ZoomZoom]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import org.jdesktop.jxlayer.JXLayer;
import org.pbjar.jxlayer.demo.TransformUtils;
import org.pbjar.jxlayer.plaf.ext.transform.DefaultTransformModel;

public class TestJLayerZoom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestJLayerZoom();
    }

    public TestJLayerZoom() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JXLayer<JComponent> layer;
        private DefaultTransformModel transformModel;
        private JPanel content;

        public TestPane() {

            content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello");
            JTextField field = new JTextField("World", 20);

            content.add(label, gbc);
            content.add(field, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            final JSlider slider = new JSlider(50, 200);
            slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    int value = slider.getValue();
                    double scale = value / 100d;
                    transformModel.setScale(scale);
                }
            });
            content.add(slider, gbc);

            transformModel = new DefaultTransformModel();
            transformModel.setScaleToPreferredSize(true);

            Map<RenderingHints.Key, Object> hints = new HashMap<>();
            //hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            //hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            //hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

            layer = TransformUtils.createTransformJXLayer(content, transformModel, hints);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(layer);


        }

    }

}
```

I've left the rendering hints in to demonstrate their use, but I found that they screwed with the positing of the cursor within the text field, but you might like to have a play

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add that I fixed the zooming issue not in the way suggested by the answer, but just by keeping the line that applied a scaled transform call in the `ExamplePanel` paintComponent method:

```
g2.scale(zoom, zoom);
```

I thought that this was the nicest implementation since none of the components require any knowledge about zooming and it seemed far simpler than `JLayer` since I only required basic zooming functionalities.

Comment: The problem is, this does not translate mouse events, which is what `JLayer` will offer, hence the reason it is recommended. There are also other issues. The parent container doesn't actually have to be part of the paint process, child components can be painted without invoking paint of the parent container, skipping your zoom setup...

Comment: Ah you're right, although I've been playing around with the `TestWrapped` demo by changing it to magnify the whole page. It doesn't seem to translate mouse events properly either. For example when drawing on the page it is not where my cursor is.