# Eclipse/ Java very small Dialog window

Tags: java, eclipse, joptionpane

I'm new in Java and Eclipse. I'm trying to use `JOptionPane` class for GUI and getting user input. 
When I run the program, I see a very small Java dialog window (attached PrtScr). The same program/ dialog window in other computers shows up with bigger size. 
Display resolution of my system is 3200 x 1800 (recommended).
How can I make bigger the default size of this dialog window?
Thank you

[PrtScr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Me19.png)

Comment: This is a HiDpi problem. I can't really say if JAVA give you any option ... Eclipse just add the manage in the NEON version, could be good to see how they manage it.

Comment: There is a "solution" here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149453/java-swing-application-too-small-in-hidpi-computers

Answer (score 0):

You can change your dialog window size with a several options:

1.by using the UIManager

```
   UIManager.put("OptionPane.minimumSize",new Dimension(800,600)); 
   JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "msg", "title", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
```

2.by resizing dialog size

```
  JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("msg", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
  JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "title");
  dialog.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
  dialog.show();
```

3.by putting your dialog window into another Panel, JScrollPane, etc. and resize this Panel

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(panel, panel, "title", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
```

Comment: And what about the font ? And when you are going to switch to a Full HD screen ? This is due to his HiDPI screen, if you need to force the size of everything, this is going to be painfull.

Comment: you are absolutely right! And of course it has to be taken into consideration. But I just answerd quesiton: _"How can I make bigger the default size of this dialog window? "_

Comment: Window size changed by importing java.awt.Dimension, but as mentioned fonts are still very small.