# Changing the fonts of all JLabels , JTextFields n JButtons in all frames of My Project

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, fonts

I am making a project based on Java **swing** as it is a GUI based project. I need to be able to change Font of my Entire project with another GUI Frame. 
Like If I made a GUI to select any font from the `JCombobox` with a ***Submit*** button
Then after selecting a font for eg. **Arial** all the Frames fonts containing `JLabel` &`JTextfield` & every other swing component

Should change its font to **Arial**

I searched over the Internet but was not able to find anything specific
I found a bit about

> **Config File**
>   For Java

I also have searched for PropertyChangeListener but it kind of did not work for me to change the fonts of all my frames as it was complicated.

Could anyone help me solve my problem

Comment: You mean something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149453/java-swing-application-too-small-in-hidpi-computers/34152675#34152675)?

Comment: See also [*Modifying the Look and Feel*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html).

Comment: @MadProgrammer din't get you 

Comment: @trashgod thank you but I am not looking to change LookAndFeel of the GUI . I only want to change the font of Components

Comment: @KaustubhGurudattKamat There's a link in that comment, to a runnable example which I believe demonstrates what you're asking, click and have a look

Comment: Like in paint application there is Text font selecting comboBox . We select a **Font** and then write with that font. But instead of writing I want to change Font of Components in my project.

Comment: 1) This is best addressed in using a custom Look and Feel. 2) Don't presume Arial will be available on all OS. Instead use `Font.SANS_SERIF` which should result in Arial on Windows, Helvetica on OS X and the default undecorated font on *nix systems. 3) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah kind of same only changing font for all frames there are in project . N thank you this will help me a lot too. 

Comment: @AndrewThompson Okies me try and see that  thank you

Comment: @KaustubhGurudattKamat Well, that example would update ALL UI components within the given JVM, so it won't matter how many frames you have it, they'd all be updated

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank You. Me trying out the program to change fonts. I have taken 5 different fonts to be able to change. In all frames. Starting with a default **Georgia** font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the tutorial about [PropertyChangeListeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html).

Comment: It's good. Actually I checked this site before. And I tried to do some coding ,based on the **PropertyChangeListener** too. But it only complicated the Project. Is it possible to do it in more simple and elegant way. As Coding should be Kept Simple. And still get my job done

Comment: *"Actually I checked this site before."* The question should detail what you have already tried & why it failed to work. Please edit the question to include all relevant information. If you could not be bothered giving us enough information to help, why should we bother trying?

Comment: @AndrewThompson  Sorry for that but me first of all did not understand what and how to use it perfectly. Me did tried it out after searching but did not got my result. So me though it would not work. Or may be there is some other way to do it. As I am a newbie in stackOverflow I apologise for an incomplete Question. I will update it in a moment

Comment: @AndrewThompson and as for y it did not work. I really have no idea about it. Sorry 