# Enlarge the User Interface Components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have made a simple UI containing buttons, a table, radio box. I got a new demand to enlarge the UI by 50%, like a magnified view, everything bigger.

Is there any way inbuilt in Java to do that ?
or 
I have to individually resize every component in the frame?

Comment: Well, [that's one way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149453/java-swing-application-too-small-in-hidpi-computers/34152675#34152675) and [here's another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174997/how-to-add-mouselistener-to-item-on-java-swing-canvas/21175125#21175125)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java swing application too small in ~HiDpi~ computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149453/java-swing-application-too-small-in-hidpi-computers)