# how to increase the size of the icons in the GUI and the size of the text using Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, zooming

Is there a way to create a feature, which magnifies all the icons in the GUI as well as all the text, from which a user can work from instead of having to work from the version which isn't magnified.

Currently I have a zoombox, which acts like a magnifying lens but you cannot write and click icons in the magnified lens. it also only magnifies what the mouse is pointing at.

Comment: The best approach for the test is probably via a custom PLAF (that uses larger fonts). That won't help with the icons though.

Comment: Maybe something like J/JXLayer, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174997/how-to-add-mouselistener-to-item-on-java-swing-canvas/21175125#21175125), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439341/zooming-jlayeredpane-via-jlayer-and-the-layerui/21445118#21445118)