# java Jlayeredpane zoom, loo childrens mouse events

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, zooming, jlayeredpane

Following this example:

[Zooming JLayeredPane via JLayer and the LayerUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439341/zooming-jlayeredpane-via-jlayer-and-the-layerui/45847056?noredirect=1#comment78652180_45847056)

but I have a problem. Inside the panel I have several j panels, dragables and resizable, and when I am not in zoom 1 I lose the possibility to select them with the mouse. Do you have any idea why? Thank you!!!

Comment: You may want to include your code so people can review and provide a response

Answer (score 0):

The code is the same as the example, but here it goes

TestJLayerZoom.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;




public class TestJLayerZoom {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                ZoomUI layerUI = new ZoomUI();
                JLayer<JComponent> jLayer = new JLayer<JComponent>(panel, layerUI);

                JButton zoomIn = new JButton("Zoom In");
                zoomIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        layerUI.zoom += 0.1;

                        jLayer.revalidate();
                        jLayer.repaint();
                    }
                });
                panel.add(zoomIn);

                JButton zoomOut = new JButton("Zoom Out");
                zoomOut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        layerUI.zoom -= 0.1;
                        jLayer.revalidate();
                        jLayer.repaint();
                    }
                });
                panel.add(zoomOut);

                frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
                frame.add(jLayer);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

ZoomUI.java

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLayer;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;


public class ZoomUI extends LayerUI<JComponent> {

        public double zoom = 1; // Changing this value seems to have no effect

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.scale(zoom, zoom);
            super.paint(g2, c);
            g2.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void installUI(JComponent c) {
            super.installUI(c);
            JLayer jlayer = (JLayer) c;
            jlayer.setLayerEventMask(
                    AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.ACTION_EVENT_MASK
                    | AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
            JLayer jlayer = (JLayer) c;
            jlayer.setLayerEventMask(0);
            super.uninstallUI(c);
        }
    }
```

[In the image I explain the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHfhM.gif)