# Zooming panel in and out but scrollbar don't work

Tags: java, swing

I have created a panel with zoom in and out function but the scrollbar don't work, I mean when I zoom in I can't scroll to see the entire panel.
This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PanelWithZoom extends JPanel{

    private JButton btnZoomIn;
    private JButton btnZoomOut;
    private double scale = 1;
    private JPanel innerPanel;
    private JPanel outerPanel;
    public PanelWithZoom() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        btnZoomIn = new JButton("zoom in");
        btnZoomIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                scale = scale + 0.1;
                outerPanel.repaint();
                outerPanel.revalidate();
            }
        });
        panel.add(btnZoomIn);

        btnZoomOut = new JButton("zoom out");
        btnZoomOut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                scale = scale - 0.1;
                outerPanel.repaint();
                outerPanel.revalidate();
            }
        });
        panel.add(btnZoomOut);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        add(panel_1, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        add(panel_2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
        add(panel_3, BorderLayout.EAST);

        outerPanel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;             
                int w = (int) getWidth();
                int h = (int) getHeight();
                // Translate used to make sure scale is centered
                g2.translate(w/2, h/2);
                g2.scale(scale, scale);
                g2.translate(-w/2, -h/2);
            }


        };
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(outerPanel);
        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        innerPanel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;             
                g2.setColor(Color.white);
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                g2.setColor(Color.black);
                g2.drawString("String for test", 10, 50);
                g2.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
                setPreferredSize(new Dimension(595, 842));
            }

        };

        outerPanel.add(innerPanel);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new PanelWithZoom());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

you can test it to understand what I mean.

Comment: You have to change the value returned from `getPreferredSize` of the component in the `JScrollPane`

Comment: sorry I don't understand you, where shoul I write that ?

Comment: Use `Graphics#create` to make a copy of the properties of the `Graphics` context and then `Graphics#dispose` when you're done, it's safer when you're manipulating the translation/scale/transformation properties ;)

Comment: Sorry still don't understand u, can you please write a simple code to make this clear ?

Comment: Think about this, in order for a scaling operation to have any meaning, you need to know the original size of what ever you are scaling.  `JScrollPane` uses the `preferredSize` property of the component to determine whether it needs to display the scroll bars or not.  When you can the scale of the `Graphics`, you are not effecting the physical properties of the component, so the `JScrollPane` doesn't know anything has changed.  So you need to scale the "original" size of the component as well and trigger an update using `revalidate` and `repaint` on the scroll pane or viewport

Answer (score 1):

Override the `getPreferredSize` method of your component, return the size of the component based on the `scale` and original size of the component.

Because you want to apply scaling to the child components, you will probably want to override `paint` instead of `paintComponent`

```
outerPanel = new JPanel(){
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();             
        g2.scale(scale, scale);
        super.paint(g);
        g2.dispose()
    }
}
```

BUT, Swing components can be painted independently of their parent containers, meaning the the `paint` method may not be called when the child component is painted...

The problem with this is, it won't scale the mouse events (or a bunch of other properties).

With an ever mounting list of issues, a better solution is to use something like JXLayer, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174997/how-to-add-mouselistener-to-item-on-java-swing-canvas/21175125#21175125)

Side notes:

- Use `Graphics#create` to copy the properties of the `Graphics` context and `Graphics#dispose`, it's safer when dealing with translation/transformations/rendering hints and bunch of other properties, as any changes to the copy won't effect the original
- Don't call any method from within any paint method which might directly or indirectly cause a repaint event to be triggered, you'll end up in a nasty never ending loop which will eventually consume your CPU

## Graphics#create and #Dispose example...

```
outerPanel = new JPanel(){
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();             
        int w = (int) getWidth();
        int h = (int) getHeight();
        // Translate used to make sure scale is centered
        g2.translate(w/2, h/2);
        g2.scale(scale, scale);
        g2.translate(-w/2, -h/2);
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: You said "Override the getPreferredSize method of your component" I have two panels "innerPanel" and "outerPanel",  wich one so you mean ?

Comment: Technically both, but the one which is applying the scaling operation would be my first recomendation

Comment: I used Graphics#create and Graphics#dispose but now the zoomIn function doesn't work anymore !

Comment: Did you take the time to have a read of the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) to find out what the methods do and maybe how to use them?

Comment: (ps Sorry, it's late and I have a sick PC I'm trying to fix, so I'm a little distracted ;))