# Swing component resize automatically by affine Transform

Tags: java, swing, refactoring, graphics2d, affinetransform

I have a Swing application with standard size and I would like to refactor all the components, which takes long time. I used `AffineTransform` with `JXlayer`. I'm able to view the resized components but not able to get and print the new resized dimensions. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The question that begs to be asked is, why aren't you making better use of one or more layout managers

Comment: Thanks for the suggest but my application as developed very long back ago. and as large code to change to layout managers. I tried with your solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174997/how-to-add-mouselistener-to-item-on-java-swing-canvas . And quite happy with result . But in that I would like to have the resized components dimensions of a component. where I am Printing the logs it showing the old dimensions but displaying resized component. Can u help me out.

Comment: Not really, as the components are actually resized, it's just that when they are painted, the `Graphics` context has been scaled.  The best you can do is take the current size/position and manually apply the scaling factor to them

Comment: public void manualScaling(Component Comp){
        int w = (int) Comp.getWidth();
        int h = (int) Comp.getHeight();
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics gtest = bi.getGraphics();
        gtest.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
       float[] scales = { 1.5f };
        float[] offsets = new float[4];
        RescaleOp rop = new RescaleOp(scales, offsets, null);
        Graphics2D g2test = (Graphics2D) gtest;
        g2test.drawImage(bi, rop, 0, 0);
        System.out.println(bi.getHeight()+"-" + bi.getWidth());
}

Comment: Hi @MadProgrammer From the above I wrote a method to scale a jComponent manually from graphic 2d  I am drawing the image and printing the dimensions but again getting the same old dimensions . I didnt get where I went wrong....

Comment: The physical dimensions of the components don't/won't change, because you're not scaling the components, you simply scaling how they are rendered

Comment: @MadProgrammer ok I understand , My target is that with the new scaling dimensions I need to calculate the remaining space that I have in the frame and I need to  Increase the other components  with in that space. Is that possible ? :(

Comment: Hi @MadProgrammer . With your solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174997/how-to-add-mouselistener-to-item-on-java-swing-canvas. I converted JXlayer to Jlayer in the Code. But In that I am unable to setLayer(LayoutManger mgr) through JLayer(not supported) as it is override from container.  Previously you are doing with Container SetLayout(LayoutManganer mgr). . Is it possible to set the Layourmanager object from JLayer?

Comment: I’ve not had the time to explore JLayer so i can’t say