# Calling the Container setLayout method by JLayer instance

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, containers, jlayer

I need to set  LayourManager in JLayer  . But JLayer doesnt support the Layoutmanager I need to call the Container setLayout by JLayer instance object. How it is possible?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer when you try to execute the code you've posted in your comment - you'll get an `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: Okay, from the docs we can see, that you are by no means supposed to use this on the `JLayer`. So please explain why you want to do it/ what you want to achieve

Comment: Yes, this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) and an unclear one at that. Original poster, please explain the behavior you're trying to elicit and less how you're trying to go about doing this, because your approach is likely wrong.

Comment: I am Doing Affine Transform Scaling tech to my application.For that I am Using LayerUI and Jlayer Implementation Tech. With the following solution.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174997/how-to-add-mouselistener-to-item-on-java-swing-canvas.   This URL Solution is done by JXlayer. I am trying with JLayer . For that  I need to set LayoutManager Instance with JLayer. Which is not supported.

Comment: I would think the layout manager would be added to the panel that is used with the JLayer. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Decorate Components With the JLayer Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) for working examples to get you started.