# Can the visual pointer component of a JSlider be accessed and modified?

Tags: java, swing, components, jslider

I am developing an application that tries to zoom a generic window (`JFrame` or `JDialog`).
I found the problem that when a `JSlider` component is to be zoomed, the visual pointer `Component` does not zoom, even though the bounds of the `JSlider` itself have been changed. 
I have looked for a function in the `JSlider` public API a function that returns an object of base class `Component`, that can be modified, but I have not found any.
Also the function `jSlider1.getComponentCount()` returns 0.
I have also looked inside the `SliderUI` class in case there was a suitable function there, without success.
Does anyone know the correct way to access the visual pointer `Component` of the `JSlider`?  Or at least how to set its size, for being able to zoom it?

Comment: I would generally think do, as it’s handled by ui delegate/look and feel

Comment: You could have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174997/how-to-add-mouselistener-to-item-on-java-swing-canvas/21175125#21175125) which uses JLayer/JXLayer to scale an active component

Comment: Wow, it sounds great!   I will have a look when I have a moment.

Comment: Finally I created a pair of classes overriding JSlider and MetalSliderUI.
I will show how those classes are if I find the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As I previously said in the comment, I finally decided to override JSlider and MetalSliderUI classes.
At least this is compatible with Java-8, as the code I started from was the one of oracle JDK-8.

The code for the example of use of the new the classes is the following.

New interface:

```
public interface ZoomInterface
{
    public void setZoomFactor( double zoomFactor );
    public double getZoomFactor();
}
```

New overriden classes:
ZoomMetalSliderUI:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalSliderUI;

/**
 *
 * @author Francisco Javier Rojas Garrido <frojasg1@hotmail.com>
 */
public class ZoomMetalSliderUI extends MetalSliderUI implements ZoomInterface
{
    protected double _zoomFactor = 1.0D;

    public ZoomMetalSliderUI()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getThumbSize()
    {
        Dimension result = ViewFunctions.instance().getNewDimension( super.getThumbSize(), null, _zoomFactor );

        return( result );
    }

    @Override
    public void setZoomFactor(double zoomFactor)
    {
        _zoomFactor = zoomFactor;
    }

    @Override
    public double getZoomFactor()
    {
        return( _zoomFactor );
    }

    @Override
    public void paint( Graphics g, JComponent c )
    {
        calculateGeometry();
        super.paint(g, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintThumb(Graphics g)  {
        Rectangle knobBounds = thumbRect;

//        g.translate( knobBounds.x, knobBounds.y );

        Icon icon = null;
        if ( slider.getOrientation() == JSlider.HORIZONTAL ) {
            icon = horizThumbIcon;
        }
        else {
            icon = vertThumbIcon;
        }

        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage( icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(),
                                                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
        Graphics g1 = bi.getGraphics();

        if ( slider.getOrientation() == JSlider.HORIZONTAL ) {
            horizThumbIcon.paintIcon( slider, bi.getGraphics(), 0, 0 );
        }
        else {
            vertThumbIcon.paintIcon( slider, bi.getGraphics(), 0, 0 );
        }

        Rectangle tr = new Rectangle( 0, 0, icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight() );
        Rectangle newRectangle = ViewFunctions.instance().getNewRectangle(tr, null, _zoomFactor );
        BufferedImage bi_tx = ImageFunctions.resizeImage(bi, (int)newRectangle.getWidth(),
                                                        (int)newRectangle.getHeight(),
                                                        null, null, null );

        Point center = ViewFunctions.instance().getCenter(knobBounds);
        g.drawImage( bi_tx, center.x - newRectangle.width / 2,
                            center.y - newRectangle.height / 2,
                            center.x + newRectangle.width / 2,
                            center.y + newRectangle.height / 2,
                            0,
                            0,
                            bi_tx.getWidth(),
                            bi_tx.getHeight(),
                            null );
//        g.translate( -knobBounds.x, -knobBounds.y );


    }


    public void paintTrack(Graphics g)  {
/*        if (MetalLookAndFeel.usingOcean()) {
            oceanPaintTrack(g);
            return;
        }
*/
        Color trackColor = !slider.isEnabled() ? MetalLookAndFeel.getControlShadow() :
                           slider.getForeground();

//        boolean leftToRight = MetalUtils.isLeftToRight(slider);
        boolean leftToRight = isLeftToRight(slider);

        g.translate( trackRect.x, trackRect.y );

        int trackLeft = 0;
        int trackTop = 0;
        int trackRight;
        int trackBottom;

        // Draw the track
        if ( slider.getOrientation() == JSlider.HORIZONTAL ) {
            trackBottom = (trackRect.height - 1) - getThumbOverhang();
            trackTop = trackBottom - (getTrackWidth() - 1);
            trackRight = trackRect.width - 1;
        }
        else {
            if (leftToRight) {
                trackLeft = (trackRect.width - getThumbOverhang()) -
                                                         getTrackWidth();
                trackRight = (trackRect.width - getThumbOverhang()) - 1;
            }
            else {
                trackLeft = getThumbOverhang();
                trackRight = getThumbOverhang() + getTrackWidth() - 1;
            }
            trackBottom = trackRect.height - 1;
        }

        if ( slider.isEnabled() ) {
            g.setColor( MetalLookAndFeel.getControlDarkShadow() );
            g.drawRect( trackLeft, trackTop,
                        (trackRight - trackLeft) - 1, (trackBottom - trackTop) - 1 );

            g.setColor( MetalLookAndFeel.getControlHighlight() );
            g.drawLine( trackLeft + 1, trackBottom, trackRight, trackBottom );
            g.drawLine( trackRight, trackTop + 1, trackRight, trackBottom );

            g.setColor( MetalLookAndFeel.getControlShadow() );
            g.drawLine( trackLeft + 1, trackTop + 1, trackRight - 2, trackTop + 1 );
            g.drawLine( trackLeft + 1, trackTop + 1, trackLeft + 1, trackBottom - 2 );
        }
        else {
            g.setColor( MetalLookAndFeel.getControlShadow() );
            g.drawRect( trackLeft, trackTop,
                        (trackRight - trackLeft) - 1, (trackBottom - trackTop) - 1 );
        }

        // Draw the fill
        if ( filledSlider ) {
            int middleOfThumb;
            int fillTop;
            int fillLeft;
            int fillBottom;
            int fillRight;

            if ( slider.getOrientation() == JSlider.HORIZONTAL ) {
                middleOfThumb = thumbRect.x + (thumbRect.width / 2);
                middleOfThumb -= trackRect.x; // To compensate for the g.translate()
                fillTop = !slider.isEnabled() ? trackTop : trackTop + 1;
                fillBottom = !slider.isEnabled() ? trackBottom - 1 : trackBottom - 2;

                if ( !drawInverted() ) {
                    fillLeft = !slider.isEnabled() ? trackLeft : trackLeft + 1;
                    fillRight = middleOfThumb;
                }
                else {
                    fillLeft = middleOfThumb;
                    fillRight = !slider.isEnabled() ? trackRight - 1 : trackRight - 2;
                }
            }
            else {
                middleOfThumb = thumbRect.y + (thumbRect.height / 2);
                middleOfThumb -= trackRect.y; // To compensate for the g.translate()
                fillLeft = !slider.isEnabled() ? trackLeft : trackLeft + 1;
                fillRight = !slider.isEnabled() ? trackRight - 1 : trackRight - 2;

                if ( !drawInverted() ) {
                    fillTop = middleOfThumb;
                    fillBottom = !slider.isEnabled() ? trackBottom - 1 : trackBottom - 2;
                }
                else {
                    fillTop = !slider.isEnabled() ? trackTop : trackTop + 1;
                    fillBottom = middleOfThumb;
                }
            }

            if ( slider.isEnabled() ) {
                g.setColor( slider.getBackground() );
                g.drawLine( fillLeft, fillTop, fillRight, fillTop );
                g.drawLine( fillLeft, fillTop, fillLeft, fillBottom );

                g.setColor( MetalLookAndFeel.getControlShadow() );
                g.fillRect( fillLeft + 1, fillTop + 1,
                            fillRight - fillLeft, fillBottom - fillTop );
            }
            else {
                g.setColor( MetalLookAndFeel.getControlShadow() );
                g.fillRect(fillLeft, fillTop, fillRight - fillLeft, fillBottom - fillTop);
            }
        }

        g.translate( -trackRect.x, -trackRect.y );
    }

    static boolean isLeftToRight( Component c ) {
        return c.getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight();
    }
}
```

ZoomJSlider:

```
import javax.swing.BoundedRangeModel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalSliderUI;

/**
 *
 * @author Francisco Javier Rojas Garrido <frojasg1@hotmail.com>
 */
public class ZoomJSlider extends JSlider implements ZoomInterface
{
    protected double _zoomFactor = 1.0D;

    public ZoomJSlider() {
        super();
    }

    public ZoomJSlider(int orientation) {
        super(orientation);
    }

    public ZoomJSlider(int min, int max) {
        super(min, max);
    }

    public ZoomJSlider(int min, int max, int value) {
        super(min, max, value);
    }

    public ZoomJSlider(int orientation, int min, int max, int value)
    {
        super(orientation, min, max, value);
    }

    public ZoomJSlider(BoundedRangeModel brm)
    {
        super( brm );
    }

    public void switchToZoomUI()
    {
        ComponentUI compUi = getUI();
        ComponentUI newUi = null;

        if( ( compUi instanceof MetalSliderUI ) &&
            !( compUi instanceof ZoomMetalSliderUI ) )
        {
            newUi = new ZoomMetalSliderUI();
        }

        if( newUi != null )
        {
            setUI(newUi);
            ( (ZoomInterface) newUi ).setZoomFactor(_zoomFactor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setZoomFactor( double zoomFactor )
    {
        _zoomFactor = zoomFactor;
        ComponentUI compUi = getUI();

        if( compUi instanceof ZoomInterface )
        {
            ZoomInterface zi = (ZoomInterface) compUi;
            zi.setZoomFactor(zoomFactor);
        }

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public double getZoomFactor()
    {
        return( _zoomFactor );
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Francisco Javier Rojas Garrido <frojasg1@hotmail.com>
 */
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(MetalLookAndFeel.class.getName());

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MetalLookAndFeel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MetalLookAndFeel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MetalLookAndFeel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MetalLookAndFeel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try
                {
                    new Window().setVisible(true);
                }
                catch( Throwable th )
                {
                    th.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Window class:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Francisco Javier Rojas Garrido <frojasg1@hotmail.com>
 */
public class Window extends JFrame implements ChangeListener
{
    protected Dimension _dimen = new Dimension( 250, 30 );
    protected ZoomJSlider _jSlider = null;
    protected javax.swing.JPanel _jPanel1;

    public Window()
    {
        super( );
        initComponents();

        setListeners();
    }

    protected void initComponents()
    {
        _jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        _jPanel1.setLayout(null);
        _jSlider = new ZoomJSlider( 50, 200, 100 );
        _jPanel1.add( _jSlider );
        _jSlider.switchToZoomUI();
        _jSlider.setBounds( 20, 30, (int) _dimen.getWidth(), (int) _dimen.getHeight() );

        getContentPane().add(_jPanel1);
        _jPanel1.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 120);

        setSize( 650, 170 );
        setLocation( getCenteredLocationForComponent( this ) );
    }

    protected void setListeners()
    {
        _jSlider.addChangeListener( this );
    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged( ChangeEvent ce )
    {
        double zoomFactor = _jSlider.getValue() / 100.0D;
        _jSlider.setZoomFactor( zoomFactor );

        Dimension size = ViewFunctions.instance().getNewDimension(_dimen, null, zoomFactor);
        _jSlider.setBounds( _jSlider.getX(), _jSlider.getY(),
                            (int) size.getWidth(), (int) size.getHeight() );
    }

    public static Point getCenteredLocationForComponent( Component comp )
    {
        int width = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
        int height = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
        Point result = new Point( width/2 - comp.getWidth()/2, height/2 - comp.getHeight()/2 );

        return( result );
    }
}
```

Other classes:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;
import java.awt.image.Raster;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class ImageFunctions
{
    public static BufferedImage resizeImage( BufferedImage original, int width, int height, Integer switchColorFrom,
                                            Integer switchColorTo, Integer alphaForPixelsDifferentFromColorFrom ) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        int alpha = 0xFF000000;
        if( alphaForPixelsDifferentFromColorFrom != null )
            alpha = ( (alphaForPixelsDifferentFromColorFrom) & 0xFF ) << 24;

        if( ( width < 1 ) || ( height < 1 ) )       throw( new IllegalArgumentException( "Bad size for image.   Width: " + width + ". Height: " + height ) );

        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage( width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );

        double factorX = ((double) original.getWidth()) / width ;
        double factorY = ( (double) original.getHeight() ) / height;

        int[] pixels = getRGB( 0, 0, original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), original );

        double transformedY = 0.5d;
        for( int tY = 0; tY < height; transformedY += 1, tY++ )
        {
            int originalOffsetY = (int) ( Math.floor(transformedY*factorY) ) * original.getWidth();
            double transformedX = 0.5D;
            for( int tX = 0; tX < width; transformedX += 1, tX++ )
            {
                int originalX = (int) ( Math.floor( transformedX*factorX ) );

                int pixelColor = pixels[ originalOffsetY+originalX ];

                if( ( switchColorFrom != null ) && ( pixelColor == switchColorFrom ) )
                {
                    if( switchColorTo != null ) pixelColor = switchColorTo;
                    else                        pixelColor = pixelColor & 0xFFFFFF;
                }
                else if( alphaForPixelsDifferentFromColorFrom != null )
                {
                    pixelColor = pixelColor & 0xFFFFFF | alpha;
                }

                result.setRGB( tX, tY, pixelColor );
            }
        }

        return( result );
    }


    /**
    * Returns an array of integer pixels in the default RGB color model
    * (TYPE_INT_ARGB) and default sRGB color space,
    * from a portion of the image data.  Color conversion takes
    * place if the default model does not match the image
    * <code>ColorModel</code>.  There are only 8-bits of precision for
    * each color component in the returned data when
    * using this method.  With a specified coordinate (x,&nbsp;y) in the
    * image, the ARGB pixel can be accessed in this way:
    * </p>
    *
    * <pre>
    *    pixel   = rgbArray[offset + (y-startY)*scansize + (x-startX)]; </pre>
    *
    * <p>
    *
    * An <code>ArrayOutOfBoundsException</code> may be thrown
    * if the region is not in bounds.
    * However, explicit bounds checking is not guaranteed.
    *
    * @param startX      the starting X coordinate
    * @param startY      the starting Y coordinate
    * @param w           width of region
    * @param h           height of region
    * @param rgbArray    if not <code>null</code>, the rgb pixels are
    *          written here
    * @param offset      offset into the <code>rgbArray</code>
    * @param scansize    scanline stride for the <code>rgbArray</code>
    * @return            array of RGB pixels.
    * @see #setRGB(int, int, int)
    * @see #setRGB(int, int, int, int, int[], int, int)
    */
    public static int[] getRGB(int startX, int startY, int w, int h,
                                BufferedImage bi )
    {
        ColorModel colorModel = bi.getColorModel();

        Raster raster = bi.getRaster();
//      WritableRaster raster = colorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster( bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight() );

        int scansize = w;
        int offset =0;

        int yoff  = offset;
        int off;
        Object data;
        int nbands = raster.getNumBands();
        int dataType = raster.getDataBuffer().getDataType();
        switch (dataType)
        {
            case DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE:
            data = new byte[nbands];
                break;
            case DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT:
                data = new short[nbands];
                break;
            case DataBuffer.TYPE_INT:
                data = new int[nbands];
                break;
            case DataBuffer.TYPE_FLOAT:
                data = new float[nbands];
                break;
            case DataBuffer.TYPE_DOUBLE:
                data = new double[nbands];
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown data buffer type: "+
                                                    dataType);
        }

        int[] rgbArray = new int[offset+h*scansize];

        for (int y = startY; y < startY+h; y++, yoff+=scansize)
        {
            off = yoff;
            for (int x = startX; x < startX+w; x++)
            {
                if( (x>=0) && (x<bi.getWidth()) && (y>=0) && (y<bi.getHeight() ) )
                {
                    rgbArray[off++] = colorModel.getRGB(raster.getDataElements( x,
                                                                                y,
                                                                                data));
                }
                else
                {
                    rgbArray[off++] = 0;
                }
           }
       }

        return rgbArray;
    }

}
```

```
public class IntegerFunctions
{
    public static int max( int i1, int i2 )
    {
        return( i1>i2 ? i1 : i2 );
    }

    public static int min( int i1, int i2 )
    {
        return( i1<i2 ? i1 : i2 );
    }

    public static int abs( int ii )
    {
        return( ii>=0 ? ii : -ii );
    }

    public static int sgn( int ii )
    {
        return( ii>0 ? 1 : ( ii<0 ? -1 : 0 ) );
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class ViewFunctions
{
    protected static ViewFunctions _instance;

    public static ViewFunctions instance()
    {
        if( _instance == null )
            _instance = new ViewFunctions();
        return( _instance );
    }

    public Dimension getNewDimension( Dimension dim, Insets insets, double zoomFactor )
    {
        Dimension result = null;

        if( dim != null )
        {
            if( insets == null )
                insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);

            int insetsWidth = insets.left + insets.right;
            int insetsHeight = insets.top + insets.bottom;
            result = new Dimension( (int) ( zoomFactor * ( dim.getWidth() - insetsWidth ) + insetsWidth ),
                                    (int) ( zoomFactor * ( dim.getHeight() - insetsHeight ) + insetsHeight ) );
        }

        return( result );
    }

    public Rectangle getNewRectangle( Rectangle rect, Insets insets, double zoomFactor )
    {
        Rectangle result = null;

        if( rect != null )
        {
            if( insets == null )
                insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);

            int insetsWidth = insets.left + insets.right;
            int insetsHeight = insets.top + insets.bottom;
            result = new Rectangle( (int) ( zoomFactor * ( rect.getX() + insets.left ) - insets.left  ),
                                        (int) ( zoomFactor * ( rect.getY() + insets.top ) - insets.top ),
                                        (int) ( zoomFactor * ( rect.getWidth()  - insetsWidth ) + insetsWidth ),
                                        (int) ( zoomFactor * ( rect.getHeight() - insetsHeight ) + insetsHeight ) );
        }

        return( result );
    }

    public Insets getNewInsets( Insets insets, double zoomFactor )
    {
        Insets result = null;

        if( insets != null )
        {
            result = new Insets( (int) ( insets.top * zoomFactor ),
                                    (int) ( insets.left * zoomFactor ),
                                    (int) ( insets.bottom * zoomFactor ),
                                    (int) ( insets.right * zoomFactor ) );
        }

        return( result );
    }

    public Point getCenter( Rectangle rect )
    {
        Point result = null;

        if( rect != null )
        {
            result = new Point( (int) ( rect.getX() + rect.getWidth() / 2 ),
                                (int) ( rect.getY() + rect.getHeight() / 2 ) );
        }

        return( result );
    }

    public Rectangle calculateNewBounds( Rectangle originalBounds, Insets insets, Point center, double zoomFactor )
    {
        Rectangle result = null;

        if( originalBounds != null )
        {
            if( insets == null )
                insets = new Insets( 0, 0, 0, 0 );

            int newX = (int) originalBounds.getX();
            int newY = (int) originalBounds.getY();
            if( center != null )
            {
                newX = (int) ( center.getX() - insets.left + ( originalBounds.getX() - center.getX() + insets.left ) * zoomFactor );
                newY = (int) ( center.getY()  - insets.top + ( originalBounds.getY() - center.getY() + insets.top ) * zoomFactor );
            }

            result = new Rectangle( newX,
                                    newY,
                                    (int) ( ( originalBounds.getWidth() - insets.left - insets.right ) * zoomFactor + insets.left + insets.right ),
                                    (int) ( ( originalBounds.getHeight() - insets.top - insets.bottom ) * zoomFactor + insets.top + insets.bottom )
                                    );
        }

        return( result );
    }
}
```